# why the loop does not run infinite in the below example?

Tags: c

This is my sample code:

```
int main()
{
    static int i = 5;
    if(--i)
    {
        main();
        printf("%d ",i);
    }   
}
```

Why is it printing `0 0 0 0`? And why the loop is not infinite? This question is picked up from geeksforgeeks.

Comment: remove `static` keyword.

Comment: Also removing the static, will cause a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: You should never call main() recursively, that's extremely poor practice. In general, recursion should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: What did you find out when you ran it under your debugger?

Comment: call `main()` after `printf("%d ",i);` I think you can understand after that

Answer (score 4):

`main` will be called by itself 4 times, with `i` being repeatedly decremented. Since `i` is `static`, the same `i` is used for all invocations of `main`.

Nothing is output to the console until the recursion is blocked. By then `i` is zero.

By the way, the behaviour on `main` calling itself is *undefined* in C++ although in C it is allowed. Make sure you switch the compiler flag to C if you're using a C++ compiler.

Comment: `main()` calling itself is not undefined in C++.   The C++ standard requires that its name not be used in any way within a program  (e.g. calling it, taking its address, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Your `if(--i)` gets at `if(0)` and this evaluates at false and exists the program. Static variables don't reinitialize themselves after they were once declared. As @Himanshu mentioned, removing the static keyword will result into an infinite loop because `i` will always have the value equal to 5.

Leaving the program as it is, your `i` will decrease till 0 and stop the loop.
The `main()` function simply calls itself and when `i == 0`, it stops from recursion and prints the stack.

Comment: The program does not exit when `i` reaches `0`.  Instead, `main` returns without recursively calling itself.  The result is quite different.

Comment: @TomKarzes, what I meant is: it simply calls itself and when `i == 0`, it stops from recursion and prints the stack.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not what you said.  Wording matters.

Comment: i just want to know why is it printing 0 since main() is before printf. Moreover, when if(0) comes it exits , so why printf is in action?

Comment: `main(); printf();`... The explanation is simple. You call main and in stack, you put the `printf`. This happens 4 times. In the function, you call main recursivly and on stack is added the `printf` because that is the only thing left after the recursive call. After your `i` gets to 0, you take whatever is left on the stack and that is printf four times. So you take 4x `printf`s from the stack and this is why you get to print 0 four times.

Answer (score 0):

static variables are created in data segment during compile time. While runtime same instance of static variable (which was created in data segment) is updated instead of creating variable `i` again and again on stack segment on each recursive call.

so, when each `main()` function returns , the same variable i created on data segment is referred by `printf()` statement, which was already decremented to 0, due to previous operations.

Now, coming to second question ,if(0) evaluates to false condition therefoure, loop ends there only.